# Как изменить уровень API в Unity для публикации в Play Market

Tags: api, sdk

Когда пытаюсь установить Уровень API системно то выбивает ошибку, что нужно вручную это делать.

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install additional SDK platform. Please run the SDK Manager manually to make sure you have the latest set of tools and the required platforms installed.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-30"

А как делать вручную не знаю.
Пробовал через командную строку, не получается.
Выбивает эту ошибку:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в андроид студио загрузить в андроид сдк версию Апи,  потом найти путь к той папке и скопировать эту папку в ту версию Юнити какую вы используете.
и в ту папку где все версии Апи